# Как записать строку подключения к локальной БД

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker

Есть БД на хосте, удалённое подключение выглядит так:

```
static string connectionString = 
$"Data Source=**.130.**.233,1433;" +
"Initial Catalog=DB;" +
"User id=sa;" +
"Password=***;";
```

При этом приложение так же находится на хосте, но в контейнере докера. Как можно установить локальное соединение между ними?

Comment: [Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/), [Networking using the host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/). Кратко: задайте `--network host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании контейнера добавить `--network host`

В строке полключения заменить `Data Source=**.130.**.233,1433;` на `Data Source=localhost;`